# jQuery Show a Textbox When an Option is Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I have the following code:

```
<select>
<option value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
<option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
<option value="Type 3">Type 3</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="other" />
```

What I want to do is using jQuery make the textbox below hidden by default, and then show it if a user selects the other option from the dropdown.

Answer (score 11):

No need for any css here.

```
$('#sel').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selected == 'Other'){
      $('#other').show();
    }
    else{
      $('#other').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: sure never heard anyone say "no need for css" before. why on earth would you ever want to avoid using css?

Comment: @David Hedlund, what's the point of using css for showing and hiding elements when jQuery has the functionality built in. I guess if you still want to do calculations with an abacus go ahead, but using show/hide is much more elegant.

Comment: Actually, I found David Hedlund's answer to be more elegant. If you look at the content rendered in firebug you'll see that css display is being used under the covers anyway.

Comment: i went with the `display` option to be able to use a ternary operation instead of a several-line `if` statement.

Comment: necroposting here, but this solution is better if you are concerned with unobstrusive design at all. If user doesn't have js enabled, the form will get displayed just fine, with david's solution, the text input will never get displayed.

Answer (score 7):

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
<option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
<option value="Type 3">Type 3</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="other" style="display: none;" />

$('#sel').change(function() {
    $('#other').css('display', ($(this).val() == 'Other') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Comment: Although Cameron didn't ask to hide the textbox if any other option was selected...

Comment: @ScottE: this is true, but I'd be very surprised if that's not what OP intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="selectbox_id">
<option value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
<option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
<option value="Type 3">Type 3</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="other" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  // hide by default
  $('other').css('display', 'none');

  $('selectbox_id').change(function(){
   if ($(this).val() === 'Other') {
     $('other').css('display', 'block');
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. It works fine except there's an extra "=" sign in the "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id = "ddlPassport" onchange = "ShowHideDiv()" style="width:150px;">
<option value="Y">Type 1</option>
<option value="Y">Type 2</option>
<option value="N">Type 3</option>
<option value="D">Other</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() 
    {
    var ddlPassport = document.getElementById("ddlPassport");
    var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
    dvPassport.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "Y" ? "block" : "none";
    dvPassport1.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "N" ? "block" : "none";
    dvPassport2.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "D" ? "block" : "none";

    }



 <div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
          <form action="viewdata.php" method="POST">
        Enter Data:
        <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" name="data" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" 
     style="float:right;width:150px;margin-top:10px;">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="dvPassport1" style="display: none">
        <form action="viewdata.php" method="POST">
        Enter Data:
        <input type="number" id="txtPassportNumber" name="data"  />
         <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" 
   style="float:right;width:150px;margin-top:10px;">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="dvPassport2" style="display: none">
        <form action="viewdata.php" method="POST">
        Enter Data:
        <input type="date" id="txtPassportNumber" name="data"  />
         <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" 
       style="float:right;width:150px;margin-top:10px;">
    </form>
    </div>
```